# getting problem in group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, group-by

i want to get the sum of quantity from the below query.
how i write the group by clause in below mention query.

```
select top 1 
EvrId,
TimeStamp,
Date,
BnhTnkMik1 as Quantity,
(select TnkCode from Tanklar where TnkId=BnhTnkId) as Tank,
FuelCode,
InvoiceNo from Evrak 
join Hareket on (BnhEvrId=EvrId)
join Stoklar on (StokId=BnhStok) 
where EvrTip=14 and EvrStatu='A'
```

Comment: Your syntax leaves a lot to be desired.  You should be using table aliases... Right now there's no way for us to really know what columns come from which tables.  The join clause does not need parenthesis, and your sub-query for the Tank field would probably be faster and more consistent as a join.

Comment: actually the feild 'BnhTnkMik1' is may contain 1 or more than one value in 'Hareket' table.i need the total quantity for specific product according to there EvrId,which maps with the column BnhEvrId.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  
    EvrId,
    sum(BnhTnkMik1) as Quantity,
from Evrak 
join Hareket on (BnhEvrId=EvrId)
join Stoklar on (StokId=BnhStok) 
where EvrTip=14 and EvrStatu='A'
group by 
    EvrId
```

Comment: thank u,but i am getting the same data as i m previously getting

Comment: @gorfor.net - You need to be more specific in your question.  What would you like the sum of?  The EvrId, or some other column?

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 
  EvrId, 
  TimeStamp, 
  Date, 
  SUM(BnhTnkMik1) as Quantity, 
  (select TnkCode from Tanklar where TnkId=BnhTnkId) as Tank, 
  FuelCode, 
  InvoiceNo 
 from 
  Evrak 
  join Hareket on (BnhEvrId=EvrId)
  join Stoklar on (StokId=BnhStok)
  where EvrTip=14 and EvrStatu='A'
 GROUP BY 
  EvrId, 
  TimeStamp, 
  Date, 
  (select TnkCode from Tanklar where TnkId=BnhTnkId), 
  FuelCode, 
  InvoiceNo
```

Comment: thanks for reply

but i m getting th following error after execution

Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.